# Update serialized object in Gemfire via rest api

Tags: gemfire

It is so happened, that in my application I work with Gemfire cache via native Gemfire client. I serialize the object and put it into cache. With rest api, which Gemfire provides, I can easily execute a get http request to get it. It somehow deserializes it, when I execute the GET HTTP

Is there a way to update my object via REST API ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A PUT HTTP request with
@type field will sole the issue, example:

> "@type": "org.apache.geode.web.rest.domain.Order"

I should have checked the docs:
https://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/91/geode/rest_apps/put_update_data.html

Comment: That goes as an attribute rather than the PdxInstance object specified which is a problem. In my case, the entry goes with the PdxInstance type org.apache.geode.pdx.PdxInstance and "@type" becomes the attribute and org.apache.geode.web.rest.domain.Order becomes the "@type" value.  What is the issue here?